# Powershell script in Add_Click

Tags: powershell

I have a working script which I would like to execute in a GUI for Powershell. In general I would like to display the selected IP (interface) from a dropdown menu as a string ("venue").
Working Script:

```
$result = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4)
$client_addr = $result.IPAddress
$octets = $client_addr.Split(".")
if ($octets[2] -eq'17' -And $octets[3] -In 2..125) {
     $venue = "venue1"}
elseif ($octets[2] -eq '178' -And $octets[3] -In 129..253) {
     $venue = "venue2"
     }
Write-Output "You are connected to $venue."
```

So I would assume to paste this code after `$OKButton.Add_Click({`and finish with

```
    [void] [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You are connected to $venue.")

})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)`
```

But unfortunately nothing happens (not even an error). Hope you can help me here out.

This is the whole code:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,500)

$result = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4)
$client_addr = $result.IPAddress
$octets = $client_addr.Split(".")

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,60) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1000,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please select interface:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

    $objCombobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox 
    $objCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,80) 
    $objCombobox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
    $objCombobox.Height = 70
    $objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 
    $objForm.Topmost = $True
    $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
    $objCombobox.Items.AddRange($client_addr) 
    $objCombobox.SelectedItem 
    
    $objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ })


 
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,420)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Name = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = "OK" 
 

$OKButton.Add_Click({
#venue1
if ($octets[2] -eq '17' -And $octets[3] -In 2..125) {
    $venue = "venue1"
    }
#venue2
elseif ($octets[2] -eq '0' -And $octets[3] -In 129..253) {
    $venue = "venue2"
    }
Write-Output $venue

[void] [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You are connected to $venue.")

})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) 


$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,420)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Name = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton) 

[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: For me it works. Show us more of the GUI code. Where is the `$objForm.ShowDialog()`? Is it before or after `$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)` ?

Comment: Where is `$OKButton` defined? Please post a complete code sample (one that can be executed to reproduce to issue)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added the complete code to the initial post

Comment: @T-Me the `$objForm.ShowDialog()` is after `$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just miss "System" for the MSGbox Call? like see below.

[**System.** Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your Message", Type of msgbox eg 'Hint',Buttons e.g. 'OK' or "YesNo","MSGBox Titel")

lookout for the space after System. i had to make it so it would show up Bold ^^

regards

Comment: Hi @crdy, I added the "System", but still same behaviour

Comment: PowerShell's type resolver implies `using namespace System`, so this is literally never necessary

Comment: MathiasR.Jessen well i'm a novice myself so i thank you for this peace of information. 
Svevak sorry i could not help you :/

Answer (score 0):

Move line 12 into the `$objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged` event. However be aware of the scope inside the scriptblock (`help about_scopes`). In your original script you apply the `.split(".")` on all availabe IPAdresses the computer has. But that can be multiple, as you know when you see the ComboBox. The code below will `.split(".")` only the `.SelectedItem`.

```
$objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ 
    $script:octets = $objCombobox.SelectedItem.Split(".")
})
```

---

Edit: If you want to show the `.InterfaceAlias` and the `.IPv4Address` in the dropdown, I would recommend to fill it with strings showing both information:

```
# Build the strings for the Combobox: 
$ItemRange = $result | ForEach-Object { "$($_.InterfaceAlias) | $($_.IPv4Address)" }
$objCombobox.Items.AddRange($ItemRange)
```

However selecting the octets is a little more complex this way:

```
$objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $script:octets = $objCombobox.SelectedItem.split("|").trim()[1].Split(".")
})
```

This will `.split()` the selected string at the `|` and `.trim()` the extra whitespaces. Then it will select part `[1]` of the two items (the first one is `[0]`) and `.split()` only this remaining IPAddress at the dots.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks for the help @T-Me!! Can I ask you one more question? How could I output the InterfaceAlias next to the IPAddress in the dropdown menu? I.e. WLAN (192.168.178.33) or vice versa (IPAddress first, than InterfaceAlias)

Comment: @Svevak do you want to write InterfaceAlias and IPAddress together in the dropdown menu or do you want to show one in the dropdown and the other in a textbox next to the menu based on the selected Item?

Comment: if I can choose, I would like to write both in the dropdown menu

Comment: @Svevak Added infos how  to show alias + IP. If the reply helps you, you could Accept it as an Answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread
[how_does_accepting_an_answer_work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: thank you so much. That works!! I accepted it as an answer.